# Should i check if a custom object is dirty before updating

Tags: c#, asp.net

So i was wondering about this today.  Is there really any need to check if a custom object of mine is dirty or not before updating the object?  The way i look at it is, checking and setting the object for a dirty state is just more calls the server has to make as opposed to making one call to the database.  If the object has not changed then nothing will change but i will still have the information on lastupdated and lastupdatedby to see someone did that. What are other peoples thoughts on this? Is it just a matter of personal preference?

Comment: I don't know, should you check?  can not checking cause you problems?  it kinda depends on the particular implementation details of your own project.

Comment: Are you talking in reference to an ORM like Entity Framework, or something else?

Comment: The pertinent question is do you **care** if the object is dirty or not? If concurrency issues and deadlocks aren't a problem, then the answer is no.

Comment: Not checking will not cause any problems.  To the Entity Framework question, i'm not for sure since i am not too familiar with the Entity framework but i think mine is a little different then that.  And to the concurrency issues question, i was not talking about checking the object to the data in the database, just checking what i have in objects. Say i load a people object and the user changes a phone number.  I put all the values in that object from the form and update to database.